# apply box-shadow to <g>inside <svg>

Tags: css, svg

```css
*{
background:black;
}
.svg{
    fill:  #2F3636;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.88889px 10px yellow;
    g{
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.88889px 10px #EDEE9B;
    }
}
```

```html
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="261"
    height="39"
    viewBox="0 0 261 39"
    class="svg"
  >
    <g style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.88889px 10px #edee9b" class="g">
      <path
        d="M246.553 0.0100098H13.4066C11.5129 0.0100098 9.97998 1.53999 9.97998 3.42999V11.94H15.7413C16.3024 11.94 16.7632 12.4 16.7632 12.96C16.7632 13.52 16.3024 13.98 15.7413 13.98H9.97998V24.41H15.7413C16.3024 24.41 16.7632 24.87 16.7632 25.43C16.7632 25.99 16.3024 26.45 15.7413 26.45H9.97998V34.86C9.97998 36.75 11.5129 38.28 13.4066 38.28H246.553C248.447 38.28 249.98 36.75 249.98 34.86V3.41998C249.98 1.52998 248.447 0 246.553 0V0.0100098Z"
        fill="white"
      />
    </g>
    <path
      d="M256.08 1.29004V18.17H259C259.56 18.17 260.02 18.63 260.02 19.19C260.02 19.75 259.56 20.21 259 20.21H256.08V37.09C256.08 37.65 255.62 38.11 255.06 38.11C254.5 38.11 254.04 37.65 254.04 37.09V1.29004C254.04 0.730039 254.5 0.27002 255.06 0.27002C255.62 0.27002 256.08 0.730039 256.08 1.29004Z"
      fill="white"
      style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.88889px 10px #edee9b"
      class="path"
    />
    <text
      x="50%"
      y="50%"
      text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="middle"
      class="svg__text"
    >
      WATCH
    </text>
  </svg>
```

I'm trying to apply box-shadow around the rectangle in SVG, which is made by the  inside , but it won't accept box-shadow. the ideal result is what's shown in the image[image]

Comment: `<g>` is not a graphical element, you cannot give it visual properties; and SVG content elements are not layed out in boxes, you cannot give them a `box-shadow`.

Comment: This is a generator I wrote to produce complex shadows in SVG - it outputs an SVG filter that you can use. https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/xxPOoX